# Current flow with a potential difference

Tags: current, ground

I have a small question, I am trying to wrap my head around the different types of ground connections in electronics.

- For earth ground connection

In an earth ground connection electrons can sink to the earth with only a single connection to earth correct? The way I am viewing it is by looking at it in a CMOS perspective. In CMOS circuits there is dynamic current flow and it is from one of the power rails to the parasitic capacitance on the output, there is no "closed path" but the current still flows. So when we have a basic resistor circuit with one resistor we can follow the same convention, in which charge will flow from a point of higher potential to a point of lower potential, there does not need to be multiple connections to ground to create a closed loop, we only need a single connection from a point of higher to lower potential.

- Floating ground

There is no actual earth connection, it is just a reference point. There will be EHP recombination at this reference point.

My main concern is about the earth ground, one connection should be enough. If we only have one connection to ground lets say it looked like this:
[image]

The positive side is at a higher potential than the ground would current flow until there is no potential differences between the source and ground?

Comment: If you pick a small battery and one side of a battery connected via a resistor to the earth's ground and the other side of a battery you left not connected (floating). No current can flow in this type of circuit.

Comment: Your circuit shows a battery with its positive terminal grounded through a 100 ohm resistor. No current will flow until you close the circuit loop. Note that we're ignoring capacitance between the negative terminal and ground as this is negligible in most cases.

Comment: That dosent make any sense though. Current is based on a potential difference. If there is a conductor and a potential difference current HAS to flow. It will be momentary until the positive end of the source has equal potential in regards to the earth. I think the "closed circuit" convention is something that makes it easier for engineers to visualize, not that it is necessarily needed. Love to hear feedback on this.

Comment: EDIT:   That dosent make any sense though. Current is based on a potential difference. If there is a conductor and a potential difference current HAS to flow. It will be momentary until the positive end of the source has equal potential in regards to the earth. This current will be transient. For a continuous current to be flowing there needs to be a closed path so the charge can return to the source. Love to hear feedback on this.

Comment: In your circuit the source's +ve terminal is at ground potential, and the source's -ve terminal is at -1V relative to ground. There is no current flowing, therefore there is no voltage across the resistor.

Comment: @Chu Yes but the point is the moment the connection happens between V+ and gnd there is a potential difference in which a transient current will flow until the potentials equal. Everyone keeps saying current won’t flow, continuous current will not flow yes since there is no path back to the source, but when there is a conductor, and a potential difference it dosent matter whether the circuit is closed or not, current will flow momentarily

Comment: The voltage on, say, the +ve terminal of a source is relative to the -ve terminal. It is not relative to any universal 'ground' reference. The same goes for the -ve terminal. If you believe that, in a 9V battery, the +ve terminal is at +9V and the -ve terminal is at -9V, relative to some universal zero volt reference, then that would mean that the potential difference across the battery would be 18V. Note that the + and - terminals of a voltage source are NOT storage areas of electrostatic charge - that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @Chu Yes agreed the voltage reference is obvious, that’s not what I’m saying. Voltage by definition is how much more potential energy a charge has at one point versus another. Having a path from a point of higher potential to a lower potential, regardless of whether the negative terminal is connected has to bring the potential to an equilibrium, therefore in the circuit above there will be a momentary surge in current..   check this thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/476792/closed-loop-circuit-vs-open-loop-circuit-can-current-flow/476793?noredirect=1#comment1209763_476793

Answer (score 0):

> In CMOS circuits there is dynamic current flow and it is from one of the power rails to the parasitic capacitance on the output, there is no "closed path" but the current still flows.

There is a closed path. The parasitic capacitance allows current to flow (momentarily) when the voltage on one side of it is changing, thus closing the path.

But this doesn't mean it flows with only one connection to the reference node. The power supply needs to connect from the reference node to the Vdd supply of the CMOS circuit, so that a complete circuit is formed, for current to flow.

> There will be EHP recombination at this reference point.

Electron-hole recombination only happens in semiconductors. It happens (as a net effect) whenever the product of elecron and hole population densities is greater than the square of the intrinsic population density (i.e. \$np>n_i^2\$). It has nothing to do with whether the semiconductor is at the reference point or not.

Comment: So lets say only the positive end of a source is connected to the load and the other side is connected directly to ground, current wont flow from the higher potential to the lower potential? There will be an emf and the wire is a conductor. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It will flow momentarily, through parasitic capacitance, until the unconnected end of the load reaches the same potential as the connected end.

Comment: Okay, thats what I was thinking. The parasitic capacitance would be between the earth and the other terminal of the source correct? So if we had only one connection to earth ground in a circuit, would the current flow to earth until it is at the same potential as earth, we wouldnt need 2 connections for current to flow momentarily.

Comment: No, between the Earth and the unconnected end of the load.

Comment: Okay, yes that makes more sense actually. So as stated above with the ground connection, if there was a single earth ground connection than that connection point to the circuit would be at the same potential with the earth. Lets say there was a surge of current that needed to flow, the earth ground would provide a place for this current to sink to momentarily correct? We wouldnt need 2 connections to ground to create a "closed circuit".

Comment: The only reason a surge current would need to flow is if something else made a connection from the earth to some other part of the earthed circuit. Or if the circuit were initially floating away from earth and picked up a static charge, and then it was connected to the earth. Once the (single-point) earthed circuit has stabilized and its reference node is at equipotential with the actual Earth, no current will flow between it and Earth.

Comment: The only thing im still confused about is does there have to be two earth ground connections for the current to momentarily flow? Or is the potential difference between the source and ground (with the negative terminal of the source not connected as shown above) constitute a "closed circuit" in which current can flow to ground. Just want to make sure im fully understanding, appreciate the help.